# Netsuite Print Templates Decimals cutting off after 3

Tags: oracle, netsuite, freemarker

I am trying to print out a custom Decimal Number field on a sublist from a Purchase Order. The print template is only giving me 3 decimals even when I have more then three. For example 10.12345678 will print as 10.123. I am doing zero formatting so it's nothing I'm doing from within the FTL file.

Anyone ran into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. When the field was created someone checked the "Apply Formatting" Checkbox.